# Allow website to be responsive whilst document.innerHTML commands are being executed

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, document.write

To summarize quickly, I have a javascript file which is injecting HTML onto a HTML file. The user picks a date from a datepicker and a CSV file is read. Every row which contains the date selected from the datepicker is then outputed as seen below:

```
let messageCode = `
     <div class="row msg_container base_sent">
          <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                <div class="messages msg_sent">
                       <p>${message}</p>
                       <time datetime="2009-11-13T20:00">${user} • ${time}</time>
                </div>
          </div>
    </div>
   `;

container.innerHTML += messageCode;
```

However, often there are around 2,000 messages which need to be outputted. This results in the user having to wait sometimes 45 seconds after selecting a date from the datepicker.

I am wondering if there is a way in which I can have the HTML injection occur whilst allowing the user to scroll. So the user is able to almost scroll down the page while HTML is being injected.

Comment: Nobody can make use of a list of 2000 items. Rethink your user experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of fetching the data from the CSV file every time a user selects a date, perhaps it would be better to fetch the file on page load, cache it and read the data from the cache.

There are plugins out there that helps with large data render, but at the moment, I can't think of one, but will inform you once I do.

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the CSV lookup task in an `async` function and `await` the returned results before injecting to the DOM.

Any code outside of your `async` function will execute and your `innerHTML` injection will run once your await lookup has returned.